# jquery slideUp when mouse out

Tags: jquery, slideup, mouseout

The following code works fine, but i'd like to alter the way sub-menus slide up: instead of clicking parent element to slide up, I'd like sub-menus to slide up when mouse is out of **all** elements of each sub-menu

```
function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul, #top-menu ul').hide();
  $('#menu ul, #top-menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
  $('#menu li a,#top-menu li a').click(
  function() {
     var checkElement = $(this).next();
     if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        return false;
     }
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        return false;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36305541/4763793

Answer (score 0):

Use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover) method. You don't need to check if element is visible or not this way:

```
$('#menu li a,#top-menu li a').hover(function(){
   $(this).next().slideDown('normal'); //on mouse over
}, function(){
   $(this).next().slideUp('normal'); //on mouse out
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine too and is a far cleaner solution. The problem is that submenu should remain visible while hovering child elements. This way it slides up when hovering child elements, and that is my main trouble.

Comment: You need to ask another question or search relevant question you'd get the answer.

Comment: I also have answered for someone. But it's I am busy so can't write right this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu li a,#top-menu li a').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
});
```

► [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

► [mouseout](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)